# Cannot suggest basic formatting edits based on whitespace: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, markdown, code-formatting

I often find myself wanting to improve new member's OPs readability by only doing basic formatting:

- adding whitespace to break down one chunk of text into several lines/sections
- adding `-` to format their successive ideas into a list
- making use of trailing 4 spaces and backticks to format their `code`, `commands` and `identifiers`.

However, I get stuck by these error messages `Edits must be at least 6 characters` and I cannot submit.

I understand that very-minor edits may be counterproductive. However, I trust that such a basic "aeration" of a chunky OP, by improving its readability, improves it a lot.

Is there any way to get around this?
If not, how should I react in this situation?